# List<List<bool>> and Contains method

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have a `List<List<bool>>` collection. I fail to check if it contains some `List<bool>` element. I've tried `Contains` method and compared elements with `==` also.

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you're looking for. You have a list of lists, and you're checking if a given list exists there. But are you checking by value or by reference? Two different instances of List<bool> will not be equal, even if they contain the same values.

Comment: Have you tried using a custom comparer?

Answer (score 1):

`Contains` and `==` check the references. These will succeed only when you have **exactly the same** List.

If you are looking for a list **with the same values**, you'l have to check them element by element.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Contains because it works for exact matching.
My suggestion is: `lst` is your list of list and `findIt` is list you searching for:

```
lst.Any(x=>x.SequenceEqual(findIt));
```

For more detail information see [SequenceEqual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx).